# rvm install 1.9.3-head: Error sort: invalid option -- V

Tags: ruby, rvm

Attempting to install ruby 1.9.3 on OSX Lion 10.7.3.  During the install I received the following errors:

```
ruby-1.9.3-head - #installing 
sort: invalid option -- V
Try `sort --help' for more information.
sed: 1: "/"name": / {s/^.*".*":  ...": extra characters at the end of p command
Retrieving rubygems-
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
The requested url does not exist: 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-.tgz'
Trying ftp:// URL instead.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:15 --:--:--     0
curl: (56) response reading failed 
There was an error, please check /Users/jakenathan/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-head/*.log
There has been an error while trying to fetch the source. 
Halting the installation.
ruby-1.9.3-head - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.9.3-head - #importing default gemsets (/Users/jakenathan/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.3-head - #complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a bug in RVM, it is fixed with this commit:
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/5282c23e3492202510116b9adc94031f101f89ac

update to latest development code with:

```
rvm get head
```

and this issue will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a macbook to test this. But according to the discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/icefox/git-hooks/issues/1) for git-hooks, the sort command in mac missing the '-V' option.

I suggest you:

1. Since you haven't provided which version of RVM you are running, update to the latest version. Also try to update git as well.
2. Post the error log file content.